# Best practice for extracting reusable getters for Svelte stores

Tags: svelte-3

Extracting update functions for stores is easy, but is there an easy way to extract getters. I'm trying to do something like this where I can reuse a getter function in multiple places. I guess my only 2 solutions are creating a derived store for every getter or combining stores into 1 custom store?

```
export function enableAll () {
    if (enableAllAllowed()) {
        storeA.update(current => { ...current, enabled: true });
        storeB.update(current => { ...current, enabled: true });
        storeC.update(current => { ...current, enabled: true });
    }
}

export function enableAllAllowed () {
    return get(StoreA).available && get(StoreB).available && get(StoreC).available && get(StoreD).canEnableAll;
}

<Component1>
   <button disabled={!enableAllAllowed()} on:click={enableAll}>
       Enable All
   </button>
</Component1>

<Component2>
   <button disabled={!enableAllAllowed()} on:click={enableAll}>       
       Enable All
   </button>
</Component2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer is as bit late, but there are many ways to get the value of  a store. Not all are reuseable, as asked for in the question, but I think it might come in handy for some folks.

The most common way to get a store value is to just subscribe to it. There are two ways. One is using the $-Syntax

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

const numberStore = writable<number>(1);

$numberStore; // Should return 1
```

an another one is unsing the subscribe function

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

const numberStore = writable<number>(1);
let value;

numberStore.subscribe(storeValue => value = storeValue)

value; // Should return 1
```

This works great for *.svelte files but not so great in *.js/*.ts files.
Luckly there are two other ways to do this.

One way is using the svelte/store get function.

```js
import { writable, get } from 'svelte/store';

const numberStore = writable<number>(1);

get(numberStore); // Should return 1
```

Another way is writing a getter function in your custom store. (Credit to: https://svelte.dev/repl/2991d70689674f50a5fb3e30216d699e?version=3.24.1)

```js
import {writable} from "svelte/store"
function createStore() {
  const { set, subscribe } = writable('PRE_GAME');
  let state
    subscribe((v)=>state=v)
  return {
    subscribe,
    set,
    preGame: (state) => state === 'PRE_GAME',
    inGame: () => state === 'IN_GAME',
    postGame: () => gamestate === 'POST_GAME',
  };
}

export const gamestate = createStore();
```